# For any two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = \langle T (v_1), T (v_2) \rangle$ if $T$ is norm-preserving.

Tags: linear-transformations, inner-products

A linear transformation $T : V \to V$ is said to be norm-preserving for a given inner product if for all vectors $v$ in $V$ the following is true:
$\langle v,v  \rangle = \langle T(v),T(v) \rangle$.

Prove that if $T$ is a norm-preserving transformation then for any vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$ in ANY inner product space $V$,  $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = \langle T (v_1), T (v_2) \rangle$.

I don’t get what I’m supposed to do, but I do know that the transformation is norm-preserving on the vector $v_1 + v_2$.

Comment: Use Polarization identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Another related post: [$T$ preserves inner product iff $\|T\alpha \|=\|\alpha\|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626701)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for any $v, w \in V$, $$\langle v + w, v + w \rangle = \langle v , v \rangle + 2 \langle v, w \rangle + \langle w, w \rangle$$

So that:

$$\langle v, w \rangle = \frac{\langle v + w, v + w \rangle  - \langle v , v \rangle - \langle w , w \rangle}{2}$$

If $T$ is norm preserving, it preserves all the terms on the right hand side, and since it is linear we have:

$$\frac{\langle T(v + w), T(v + w) \rangle  - \langle T(v) , T(v) \rangle - \langle T(w) , T(w) \rangle}{2} = \langle T(v), T(w) \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle $$

Comment: This is of course assuming the space is over the real numbers. Over the complex numbers this does not work.

Comment: Good point! You're most certainly correct. But the complex case is just a little bit more complicated.

Comment: As pointed out above, the polarization identity can then be used instead.