# Property of inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $T : V \to V$ be a linear map. I'd like to prove the following statement:

If $\|T(v)\| = \|v\|$ for all $v \in V$, then $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle T(u), T(v)\rangle $ for all $u,v \in V$.

I was advised to consider $\|T(u + v)\|$ but that approach bore no fruit.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate, I'll get you the link shortly. Till then, see [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Real_vector_spaces).

Comment: The idea to consider $\lVert T(u + v) \rVert$ is useful, because (without knowing anything about $T$ at all) we always have
$
\lVert T(u + v) \rVert^2 = (T(u + v), T(u + v)) = \lVert T u\rVert^2 + \lVert T v\rVert^2 + 2 (T u, T v)
$.
So if $\lVert T v \rVert = \lVert v \rVert$ for all $v$ then $2(T u, Tv) = \lVert u + v \rVert^2 - \lVert u \rVert^2 - \lVert v \rVert^2 = 2(u, v)$, as desired. There's the whole thing in a comment anyway.

Comment: Use the polarization formula $<x,y>=\frac{1}{4}(||x+y||^2-||x+y||^2) $ and an immediate calculation will show the result. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law)

Comment: Here you go : [$T$ preserves inner product iff $\|T\alpha \|=\|\alpha\|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626701/t-preserves-inner-product-iff-t-alpha-alpha)